# Append an output of a command to a txt file and place it in non writable directory?

Tags: command-line, scripts, sudo

If i try for example :

directory **A** i don't have write permission on it

```
sudo ls -l > /home/A/a.txt
bash: /home/A/a.txt: Permission denied
```

Then how can i do this trick , any Suggestion is appreciated .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tee` is the command people would usually use. You can pipe to it and it redirects into the file (as well as the console).

```
ls -l | sudo tee /home/A/a.txt
```

It also has an append flag (equivalent to `>>`):

```
ls -l | sudo tee -a /home/A/a.txt
```

The alternative is wrapping an entire subshell in your sudo:

```
sudo bash -c 'ls -l > /home/A/a.txt'
```

---

I preference `tee` mostly because that way you're still running the bulk of the command as the lower user. When you wrap everything in a `sudo bash -c '...'` construct, the whole thing gets executed as the root user. Redirecting something like `whoami` into another user's directory could become troublesome.

As I lead with, `tee` also bounces the output back to `STDOUT`. This makes chaining commands pretty simple.

For example if you wanted to compile a .less file into CSS (and save it) "minimise" that CSS (and save it) and then compress that minimised copy with gzip to save your server doing it (and save that).

You could use bare commands, using full filenames each time:

```
lessc less/bootstrap.less > dist/bootstrap.css
cleancss --selectors-merge-mode ie8 dist/bootstrap.css > dist/boostrap.min.css
gzip -qk9 dist/boostrap.min.css
```

or just pipe it around with tee:

```
lessc less/bootstrap.less | tee dist/bootstrap.css \
  | cleancss --selectors-merge-mode ie8 | tee dist/boostrap.min.css \
  | gzip -qc9 > dist/boostrap.min.css
```

That's code I use daily.

It probably *is* more efficient (you're saving reading from the subsequent files, `tee` keeps it in memory) but I think more than anything it's objectively prettier code. That's an underrated aspect when you're dealing with this nonsense on a day to day basis.

Comment: i tried them , thank you Oli , i found last answer when i google it , thank you

Comment: I'd preference `tee` any day of the week though. Bunging everything in a separate shell is messy and convoluted. It also means you're running the first command as root which might be impractical... For example, what if you wanted to write the output of `whoami` as your user into `/root/who-they-are`? Use `tee`.

Comment: Great explanation , as Great Oli

Answer (score 0):

You can create the file using `sudo` (or as the user owning the directory):

```
sudo touch /home/A/a.txt
```

Now you can make another user the owner of the file using:

```
sudo chown username:username /home/A/a.txt
```

*Replace `username` by the username you want to be the owner.*

Or if you want all users to be able to read and edit the file:

```
sudo chmod 666 /home/A/a.txt
```

---

**Note:** using `>` you won't append to the file. Use `>>` to append.

Answer (score 0):

**Oli** answer is Perfect , after **Google** search ,  I tried to run shell itself with privilege :

Command :

```
sudo bash -c " ls -l > /home/A/a.txt"
```

And its solved .